# What does {{ hiddenInput('enabled', '1') }} in an entry form do?

Tags: craft3, post

What's the purpose of `{{ hiddenInput('enabled', '1') }}` in an entry form?

```
<form method="post" accept-charset="UTF-8">
{{ csrfInput() }}
{{ actionInput('entries/save-entry') }}
{{ redirectInput('viewentry/{slug}') }}
{{ hiddenInput('sectionId', '2') }}
{{ hiddenInput('enabled', '1') }}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is to generate an HTML input tag with type of hidden.
This will not appear on the screen like a normal input does. 
For more information related to input type hidden, you can refer to [this](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_type_hidden.asp).

`enabled` means that the entry will be saved with its status toggle set to the “enabled” (green) position.

Comment: bro thanks for the answer...but what is it used for in a site?ie..what is the status toggle used for?

Comment: usually, it's used to sent some item for example : id user that you get from database.
But in your question this input used to determine in which section your entries will be saved. for toggle status I can't say for sure, I cannot find much documentation for this toggle.